# what are the "reasons of moderation" for which my question was deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have asked https://superuser.com/questions/813721/what-are-the-biggest-bottlenecks-for-rendering-jpeg-images ([Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hVYasosVicoJ:superuser.com/questions/813721/what-are-the-biggest-bottlenecks-for-rendering-jpeg-images+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk))

All I see now it is was deleted "for reasons of moderation".
How can I see what were particularly those "reasons of moderation"?
I've read faq about why would a question be deleted, but I can't find an explanation for my question.

Comment: It was automatically deleted because it was closed and not reopened and had a negative score.

Comment: thanks, are you able to see what was the negative score? specifically I'm interested if the negative score was just because after rewording nobody else upvoted again or did it keep getting downvotes even after rephrasing? are you able to access those statistics? if it did not receive revoting I can ask again, but if it kept getting downvoted I should not.

Comment: It scored -2. It was in the review queues twice and was voted as "leave closed".

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of why it was deleted, your question had multiple problems even after it was edited.

First of all, you're asking multiple questions in one post ("What is the most significant item…" and "what is the best way to future-proof", how you can render your images as fast as possible).

Second, those questions are too broad *and* the answers would be opinion-based.

Third, you're still asking for a product to solve your problem (we don't do product recommendations) and even if you weren't asking for a product, it would be very hard to tell what you're *actually* asking.

This is why your question didn't pass the review in the reopen queue, twice. And that's likely to be the reason for the automatic deletion.

Comment: If I leave out the second question and stop after the first question mark, is the first question still too broad for stack exchange? The initial wording was basically 'User desires that the computer to perform action X using program Y within a limited amount of time. What does he need to do in order to achieve his goal?' - is there any way this can be reworded (but still keep meaning) to be considered accepted on any SE site?

Comment: @CostinGușă: The "number of questions" isn't tied to the number of question marks in your post. If your question can be summarized into a single sentence, then it probably should. That being said, your post doesn't look like a single question. I've now read it multiple times and my best guess is that you want to know how to display a series of images in succession as fast as possible. But this still isn't a good question, because it would be impossible to predict which configuration of hardware+software would reach your set goal of 200ms (without naming specific products).

Comment: The real answer to your question is, buy the best hardware you can afford. If it still isn't fast enough, then it doesn't matter, because you couldn't afford anything better anyway. This answer is especially true because, in case it was *too* fast, then at least your requirement for future-proofing would also be met.

Comment: I would like to avoid unnecesary spending on parts that are already doing their job fast enough in the whole process of displaying an image. Buying the best hardware I can is a blind recomendation; I would rather buy the best hardware identified by the answer: which component is is most significant in the displaying of an image? So I can make a priority list.

Comment: Or if there isn't a single component, what is the list of them in order of significance

Comment: @CostinGușă And exactly that makes your question a shopping recommendation, which is off-topic for [su].

Comment: You are saying "But this still isn't a good question, because it would be impossible to predict [...] (without naming specific products).". Does naming the operating system, the image in question, the image viewver help predict the hardware needs?